# GPU tensorflow running slower than CPU tensorflow on laptop?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu, cpu

I recently installed the GPU tensorflow, CUDA and cuDNN on my laptop to train my models using my GPU using [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-tensorflow-on-the-gpu-of-your-laptop-with-ubuntu-18-04-554e1d5ea189) tutorial. My laptop is an Lenovo Ideapad 510 with Processor = i5-7th gen and GPU = GForce 940MX(4GB). Following the tutorial, I installed and configured all the required changes needed to use my GPU.

## results of training the mnist dataset on GPU

Each epoc just took 6 seconds to compile 60,000 images. And on `nvidia-smi` table I could see my GPU memory usage was 19MiB. In the tutorial, his GPU memory usage was 777MiB.

Then I tried to run my own dataset and model which has 88000 images and runs for 10 epocs. the `nvidia-smi` for this training shows GPU usage as 19MiB. `tf.test.is_gpu_available()` is also returning FALSE.

## CNN MODEL

```
classifier = Sequential()


classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (100, 100, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Flatten())

classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 39, activation = 'softmax'))

classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])



from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('train',
                                                 target_size = (100,100),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('test',
                                            target_size = (100, 100),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch = 88534,
                         epochs = 10,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         validation_steps = 1418)

classifier.save('/home/harish/Desktop/asl-alphabet/asl_pred.h5')
```

Why am I not able to train data faster than the usual CPU? How do I enable GPU for training?

Answer (score 1):

The [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-tensorflow-on-the-gpu-of-your-laptop-with-ubuntu-18-04-554e1d5ea189) you used has multiple methods of NVIDIA driver installation. I am not sure which method you used. The first method is generally not recommend because most of the time that install backdated driver.  (If you want to reinstall driver, please have a look at [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#install_cuda_with_apt) described in tensorflow official documentation.)

However,  Now come to the main point.

As `nvidia-smi` command is working, let's skip Driver installation part.

But, `tf.test.is_gpu_available()` returns `False` which can be caused by many reasons.(i.e. CuDNN or Tensorflow incompatibility with your current driver).

A **quick solutions** might be

1. Please check your current GPU driver version, and search for the suitable Tensorflow verson that has compatibility with your current GPU driver version.
2. Install tensorflow using conda environment. This will download correct CUDA, CuDNN and other necessary library.

Tensorflow gpu: `conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu=<version>`

Keras gpu `conda install -c anaconda keras-gpu=<version_match_with_tensorflow>` (however, `tf.keras` might be better instead of this separate keras install)

Comment: I am currently running GPU driver version 440.44 and NVIDIA-SMI is 430.50 the cuda version installed in system is 10.2. Is the latest version of TensorFlow compatible with these components?

Comment: Diver seems OK. However, tensorflow currently supports CUDA = `10.1` (it doesn't mention anything like `10.1`+ or `10.2`). Would you please just try with CUDA `10.1`? 

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements

Answer (score 0):

On laptops its happens an application don't wants to use the dedicated card as it is works throught the intel display. Check out if your laptop is using the Nvidia GPU in the nvidia control panel under 3d settings select High performance Nvidia graphics.